# где лучше делать забирать данные componentWillMount vs componentDidMount?

Tags: reactjs

В каком методе правильнее делать запрос к серверу за данными componentWillMount или componentDidMount?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

componentDidMount, есть хороший материал который объясняет это: https://daveceddia.com/where-fetch-data-componentwillmount-vs-componentdidmount/

Comment: Отличная статья, спасибо