# Не получается запустить поиск данных по таблице

Tags: reactjs

Отрендерил таблицу, теперь хочу задать поиск по первой колонке. Но поиск не работает. Нет ошибок и вообще нет никакой ответной реакции.

```
import React from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';
import SearchBar from './search';

const API = 'http://www.json-generator.com/api/json/get/ceRHciXcVu?indent=2';

const Header = () => {
  return (
    <thead>
      <tr>
        <td>Company</td>
        <td>Balance</td>
        <td>Registered</td>
        <td>Country</td>
        <td>Number of employers</td>
        <td>Show employers</td>
      </tr>
    </thead>
  )
}

class OurTable extends React.Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props)
        this.state = {
           hits: [],
           isLoading: false,
           filteredArr: []
        }
    }

    componentWillMount() {
        fetch(API)
          .then(response => response.json())
          .then(data => this.setState({
                          hits: data, 
                          isLoading: false,
                          filteredArr: data
                        }));
    }

    componentDidMount() {
    this.setState({ isLoading: true });
    }

    render() {
        const { hits, isLoading } = this.state;

        if (isLoading) {
            return (
                // <thead>
                    // <tr>
                    <div>
                        <p>Loading...</p>
                    </div>
                    // </tr>
                // </thead>
            );
        } else {
            return (
                <div className='wrapper'>
                    <SearchBar data={this.state} newState={this.newState.bind( this )}/>
                    <table>
                        <Header />
                        <tbody>
                            {hits.map(element =>
                                <tr key={element._id}>
                                <td>{element.company}</td>
                                <td>{element.balance}</td>
                                <td>{element.registered}</td>
                                <td>{element.address.country}</td>
                                <td>{element.employers.length}</td>
                                <td>---</td>
                                </tr>
                            )}
                        </tbody>
                    </table>
                </div>  
            );
        }
    }

    newState(prop){
        this.setState(prop);
    }
}


ReactDOM.render(<OurTable />, document.getElementById('root'));
```

Вот модуль поиска:

```
import React from 'react';

export default class SearchBar extends React.Component {
    // constructor(props) {
    //     super(props);
    // }
    render() {
        return (
          <form>
            <input type="text" placeholder="Search for company" className='form-control' onChange={ this.search.bind(this) } />
          </form>
        );
    }

    search(e){
        let word = new RegExp('^' + e.target.value, 'i'),
        filteredArr;
        if(word.length !==0) {
            filteredArr = this.props.data.hits.filter( (item) => {
                return word.test( item.company );
            });

            this.props.newState({
                filteredArr: filteredArr
            });
        } else {
            this.props.newState({
                filteredArr: this.props.data.hits
            });
        }
    } 
}
```

Comment: а как оно подключается к таблице

Comment: Теоретически, "поиск" должен поменять данные в state, а таблица должна подтянуть новые данные из этого state.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Смотрите, у вас отфильтрованный массив это `filteredArr`, а в таблице вы рисуете `hist`.

Если вы замените:

```
hits.map(element =>
```

На:

```
this.state.filteredArr.map(element =>
```

то все будет в порядке.

Еще у вас не корректно делается изменение isLoading.

`componentDidMount` срабатывает после `componentWillMount`. Вы сначала делаете запрос в `componentWillMount`, а потом говорите что у вас идет загрузка в `componentDidMount`. Если запрос выполнится до срабатывания `componentDidMount`, то вы никогда не увидите `<p>Loading...</p>`.

Советую сделать так (вообще убрать `componentWillMount` - тут есть ответ почему: [где лучше делать забирать данные componentWillMount vs componentDidMount?](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/813270/%D0%B3%D0%B4%D0%B5-%D0%BB%D1%83%D1%87%D1%88%D0%B5-%D0%B4%D0%B5%D0%BB%D0%B0%D1%82%D1%8C-%D0%B7%D0%B0%D0%B1%D0%B8%D1%80%D0%B0%D1%82%D1%8C-%D0%B4%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%BD%D1%8B%D0%B5-componentwillmount-vs-componentdidmount/813604#813604))

```
class OurTable extends React.Component {

  // так как обращение к API у вас в любом случае будет, то вы сразу можете
  // сказать что у вас состояние загрузки isLoading: true

  constructor(props) {
    super(props)
    this.state = {
       hits: [],
       isLoading: true, 
       filteredArr: []
    }
  }

  componentDidMount() {
    fetch(API)
      .then(response => response.json())
      .then(data => this.setState({
                      hits: data, 
                      isLoading: false,
                      filteredArr: data
                    }));
  }

  // Ваш остальной код здесь

}
```

Comment: Да, всё так, как вы и написали. Исправил и всё заработало.  Я до этого уже модуль с поиском несколько раз перепроверил и с пропсами возился. А ошибка оказалась там, где я не ожидал. Спасибо за развернутый ответ и вдвойне спасибо за ссылку.

Comment: @AndreyGreen рад помочь:)